# TTThumbsViewController example

Tags: iphone, three20

anyone has a working example of a TTThumbsViewController used with files
 included in the bundle?

I tried on my own but I think I'm missing something relevant. My controller
 instantiates correctly and it's initialized with a photo source and
 objects with the TTPhoto protocol.

maxPhotoIndex is called correctly but photoAtIndex never gets
 called.

What triggers the loading mechanism?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While solving this issue I hit a few different problems:

a) I'm loading my controller object with loadNibNamed before adding
it with [nav pushViewController] . viewDidLoad is not sent to the
added object unless it's a subclass of TableViewController 
(TableViewController sends viewDidLoad after instantiating the tableView)

b) My Xib file had a view as a children of the TTThumbsViewController
subclass. Once removed, the thumbnails finally appeared on the screen.

c) The URL "protocol" for the bundled files is bundle:// while the one
for the files in the documents directory is documents://

Now my controller is correctly showing both local and remote photos.

Now I have to understand how to enable the scrolling
on the pictures that are bigger than the screen.